# Erro de troca de animação

Tags: gdscript

Comecei a pouco tempo programar com *GDScript*, e estou travado em uma parte do código, onde tenho a animação de atacar em movimento que funciona normal, mas a animação atacando parado não funciona, alguém ai pode me ajudar?; Não vejo um erro de lógica aparente.

```cs
    # Lógica adicional para lidar com animações de ataque quando estiver parado
    #===========================================================================
    if (_is_attacking):
        if (_idle == "idle"):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack"
        elif (_idle == "idle_up"):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack_up"
        elif (_idle == "idle_down"):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack_down"
    #===========================================================================
```

**Código Completo**

```cs
extends CharacterBody2D

# Declaração de variáveis exportadas para o editor
@export_category("Variables")
@onready var sprite_2d = $Texture
@export var _move_speed: float = 64.0
@export var _acceleration: float = 0.2
@export var _friction: float = 0.2
@export var _attack_timer: Timer = null

# Variáveis locais
var _idle: String = "idle_down"
var _is_attacking: bool = false

func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    _move()  # Chamada da função de movimento
    _attack()  # Chamada da função de ataque
    move_and_slide()  # Função integrada do Godot para movimento físico

func _move() -> void:
    var _direction: Vector2 = Vector2(
        Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right"),
        Input.get_axis("move_up", "move_down")
    )
    
    if _direction != Vector2.ZERO:    
        _animate(_direction)  # Chama a função de animação baseada na direção do movimento
        return

    sprite_2d.animation = _idle  # Define a animação como ociosa quando não há movimento
    
    # Lógica de movimento e fricção
    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, _direction.normalized().x * _move_speed, _friction)
    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, _direction.normalized().y * _move_speed, _friction)

func _attack() -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("attack") and not _is_attacking:
        _attack_timer.start()  # Inicia o temporizador para controlar o ataque
        _is_attacking = true  # Define a flag de ataque como verdadeira

func _animate(_direction: Vector2) -> void:
    # Lógica para determinar a animação com base na direção do movimento e no estado de ataque
    if abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y):
        sprite_2d.flip_h = velocity.x < 0
        _idle = "idle"
        
        if (_is_attacking):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack"
        else:
            sprite_2d.animation = "walk"
            
    else:
        if velocity.y < 0:
            _idle = "idle_up"
            
            if (_is_attacking):
                sprite_2d.animation = "attack_up"
            else:
                sprite_2d.animation = "walk_up"
        else:
            _idle = "idle_down"
            
            if (_is_attacking):
                sprite_2d.animation = "attack_down"
            else:
                sprite_2d.animation = "walk_down"
            
    # Lógica adicional para lidar com animações de ataque quando estiver parado
    #===========================================================================
    if (_is_attacking):
        if (_idle == "idle"):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack"
        elif (_idle == "idle_up"):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack_up"
        elif (_idle == "idle_down"):
            sprite_2d.animation = "attack_down"
    #===========================================================================
    
    
    # Lógica de movimento e fricção
    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, _direction.normalized().x * _move_speed, _acceleration)
    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, _direction.normalized().y * _move_speed, _acceleration)
    
func _on_attack_timer_timeout() -> void:
    _is_attacking = false  # Reseta o estado de ataque após o tempo limite do temporizador
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar o erro na lógica. a lógica de atacar parado esta junto com a de atacar em movimento no `if _direction != Vector2.ZERO:` então só precisei mover a logica de atacar parado depois do `if`

**Código**

```cs
if _direction != Vector2.ZERO:    
    _animate_move(_direction)  
else:
    if (_is_attacking):
        match _idle:
            "idle" :
                sprite_2d.animation = "attack"
            "idle_up" :

                sprite_2d.animation = "attack_up"
            "idle_down" :
                sprite_2d.animation = "attack_down"
    else:
        sprite_2d.animation = _idle
```

Comment: Que legal que resolveu por sua conta, mas lembre-se de em próximas postagens fornecer um [mcve] no lugar do código original, aumentando a chance de obter solução rapidamente. A [help] e links lá contidos podem ajudar no entendimento do objetivo do site, e na formulação de postagens que sejam mais eficientes para obter solução e ajudar outros usuários.